# Error compiling Kernel-aodv for ARM

Tags: c, linux-kernel, arm, cross-compiling, openembedded

I'm about to implement AODV on ARM board SabreLite and I'm facing some problems.

So, I use the latest version of AODV located here (sourceforge.net/projects/aodvuu/). I've follow the instruction given in README file but at the end, i get the error:

**kaodv-mod.c:22:27: fatal error: linux/version.h: No such file or directory
 #include**

Since the board use  3.0.35 kernel version, i download it and I just change the kernel directory in Makefile. And, it should normally worked based on the instruction (http://w3.antd.nist.gov/wctg/aodv_kernel/kaodv_arm.html). The above error suggests that i don't have the version.h but I checked and I have all of linux header files installed, so it can't be that.

On the step number 6 of the tutorial (README file), i did not compile the kernel 3.0.35 because i'm pretty positive that it has the proper netfilter support for AODV-UU as it is a kernel young version. ( It is actually a configuration suggestion on kernel 2.4 and 2.6 but i think i should not obliged to do that here)

- What can be the solution of this ?
- Do i really need to compile this kernel version (3.0.35) before keep going ?
- Do i have to change the AODV code, and if so, which files do i have to modify ?

Thanks in advance !!!

---

Thanks for your response, but unfortunately, i've already done that. By saying that, i mean, i've choosen the  kernel source tree that matches the target kernel (linux-imx6-boundary-imx_3.0.35_4.1.0). I've also set up my cross compiler to have my environment variables ready for the cross compilation. Here is the output.

```
echo $CC:

arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi
```

and some of my env variables looks like this:

```
ARCH=arm

CROSS_COMPILE=arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-          

CFLAGS= -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types   

RANLIB=arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-ranlib
```

After, all of these configurations, i still got the error. I really don't think that i have to recompile the kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to build modules, you need a kernel source tree in a state that *matches the target kernel*, i.e. not an untouched freshly-downloaded one. Don't confuse the presence of extra board-specific patches/drivers/etc. in a vendor kernel for *configuration* - to get the source tree into the right state to use, you still need to:

- configure it correctly: `make ARCH=arm <whatever>_defconfig` (and/or any .config tweaks your board needs)
- then build it: `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=<your toolchain triplet>`

You need to actually build the kernel because there are many important files *that don't exist yet*, like the contents of `include/generated` (where the aforementioned version.h is created), the corresponding `arch/$ARCH/include/generated`, the checksums for module versioning, and probably more, which will all be different depending on which architecture and particular configuration options were chosen.

---

My bad for missing the mention of the crucial detail in the question, but upon downloading the linked AODV to try this myself, it became clear: the makefile is designed for the 2.4 build system which was rather different (and I'm not familiar with). Getting that one to build against a post-2.6 kernel will require [writing a new makefile](http://lwn.net/Articles/21823/).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately, i've already done that. By saying that, i mean, i've choosen the  kernel source tree that matches the target kernel (linux-imx6-boundary-imx_3.0.35_4.1.0). I've also set up my cross compiler to have my environment variables ready for the cross compilation. Here is the output.              

echo $CC:

arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi              ARCH=arm

Comment: @scof007 you still need to configure and build the kernel - it doesn't know whether to use the ARM code or the PowerPC code or whatever until you do. It's not like it's a big deal - cross-compiling an ARM kernel only takes a couple of minutes for me.

Comment: You may be able to find the original configuration in /proc/config.gz on the device.  The manufacturer should be providing it as part of their corresponding source for whatever binary kernel you have.

Comment: So,an update.,thanks for the response by the way. Actually, i configure and build the kernel, but i still get error. After config and build, i get the missing directory stated previously fixed and i also get the other directories on track such as include/generated. So i run "make arm" in aodv directory to cross compile for the arm and the error above goes away (version.h missing) but i get other "including" errors  (for instance asm/rwsem.h). the asm directory generated by config and build process don't have such file. what can i do ? Has everyone already tried to cross compile aodv for arm?

Comment: So, i get all of the include error fixed. From the start, i was not on the right kernel version, so even after configuring and building the kernel. i've still some files missing. So, i still have error but not on including anymore. So the problem stated above is resolved i think. Now, i get error along with : /usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:21:3: error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'
which is a problem from the cross compilation tree. I don't know yet how on earth i got this errors right now ...

Comment: @Notlikethat thank you for your response. So, you say that i have to write another Makefile for this post 2.6 kernel version. Well, i'll try to do that, because as i stated just above, the include missing error is gone but i still have some errors that should not happen. I've never write a Makefile for AODV before but i think that it should not be so different compared to the one that already existed (kernel 2.4). Do you happen to have any idea what changes do i have to make on this makefile ?